# netsh not working when run via Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, remoting, invoke-command

When I run the following locally on a server it works just fine.

```
$NetshArgumentList = 'advfirewall firewall add rule name="Zabbix Agent" dir=in action=allow program="C:\zabbix\bin\win64\zabbix_agentd.exe" enable=yes'
Start-Process -FilePath 'netsh' -ArgumentList $NetshArgumentList
```

But when I try to run it remotely like this it wouldn't work.

```
$ComputerName = 'Remote-Host'
$NetshArgumentList = 'advfirewall firewall add rule name="Zabbix Agent" dir=in action=allow program="C:\zabbix\bin\win64\zabbix_agentd.exe" enable=yes'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {Start-Process -FilePath 'netsh' -ArgumentList $using:NetshArgumentList}
```

Any suggestions on why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: What messages/errors are you getting back?

Comment: I don't get any error. it just seems to execute the command. how can I get a return value from that command? I've now also tried with  `-Authentication CredSSP` but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured it out. Using `Invoke-Expression` it now works. here is the working code:

```
$ComputerName = 'Remote-Host'
$NetshArgumentList = 'advfirewall firewall add rule name="Zabbix Agent" dir=in action=allow program="C:\zabbix\bin\win64\zabbix_agentd.exe" enable=yes'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression "netsh $using:NetshArgumentList"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$NetshArgumentList` isn't visible in the remote session.  You can ask PowerShell to copy it over with the `using:` [scope modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-6):

```
$ComputerName = 'Remote-Host'
    $NetshArgumentList = 'advfirewall firewall add rule name="Zabbix Agent" dir=in action=allow program="C:\zabbix\bin\win64\zabbix_agentd.exe" enable=yes'
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {Start-Process -FilePath 'netsh' -ArgumentList $using:NetshArgumentList}
```

Comment: sorry i did run it with `using:` just copy paste error in my question